# PHP - Displaying directory folders in random order

Tags: php, random, directory

The code works perfectly. Just don't know how to get it to display the content randomly without using Jquery.

Got it to display a random image from the current directory, but not sure how to get the directory to display randomly.

```
$dir = 'img/series_thumbnail/';
$dh = opendir($dir);
while (($fileName = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
  if (!in_array($fileName, array('.', '..'))) {
    $images = glob($dir . $fileName . '/*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE);
    $imgMax = count($images)-1;
    $imgNum = rand(0, $imgMax);
    $imgUrl = $images[$imgNum];
    echo '<li>';
    echo '<img src="' . $imgUrl . '"/>';
    echo '<div class="info"><p>' . $fileName . '</p></div>';
    echo '</li>';
  }
}
```

Thank you.

**EDIT**

Figured it out! Thanks for your help everyone.

```
$dir = glob("img/series_thumbnail/*", GLOB_ONLYDIR);
shuffle($dir);
foreach ($dir as $folder) {
  if (!in_array($folder, array(".", ".."))) {
    $folderName = basename($folder).PHP_EOL;
    $images = glob($folder . "/*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}", GLOB_BRACE);
    shuffle($images);
    echo "<li>";
    echo '<img src="' . $images[0] . '"/>';
    echo "<div class='info'><p>" . $folderName . "</p></div>";
    echo "</li>";
  }
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean? That code looks like it would display an image randomly. Are you trying to display all the images in the directory in random order?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php and why do you iterate when then using `glob`?

Comment: Don't edit the working code into your question. Instead, either accept the existing answer, add your own answer, or both.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display a single random image from each directory, with the directories in random order, you can use this code:

```
$dir = 'img/series_thumbnail/';
$directories = glob("$dir*", GLOB_ONLYDIR);
shuffle($directories);
foreach ($directories as $directory) {
    $images = glob($dir . $directory. '/*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE);
    $imgMax = count($images)-1;
    $imgNum = rand(0, $imgMax);
    $imgUrl = $images[$imgNum];
    echo '<li>';
    echo '<img src="' . $imgUrl . '"/>';
    echo '<div class="info"><p>' . $fileName . '</p></div>';
    echo '</li>';
}
```